# Regex: not providing length of certain string places

Tags: javascript, regex

I used to use this:

`https:\/\/foo\.bar\.com\/t\/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\/........`

But I need to let two spots in a link to have dynamic length

`\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\` - I've set this to 7 length but it needs to be working for ANY digit number

`........` - Same here, should be any characters UPPER or lower case any length needs to be allowed

Comment: `\d+` (one or mor digits), or perhaps `\d*` (zero or more digits) is what you want. This is pretty basic regex stuff, so maybe you should read a primer about regex?

Comment: Yup, do u wanna type it as answer so I can put it as solved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075